# Parsing expressions inside arithmetic expressions

Tags: parsing, haskell, compiler-construction, parsec, megaparsec

I would like to parse arithmetic expressions.

**Here is my current parser:**

```
data AExpr
    = ExprAsAExpr Expr
    | IntConst Integer
    | Neg AExpr
    | ABinary ABinOp AExpr AExpr
    deriving (Show, Eq)

aExpr :: Parser AExpr
aExpr = makeExprParser aTerm aOperators

aTerm :: Parser AExpr
aTerm
    =   parens aExpr
    <|> IntConst <$> integerParser

aOperators :: [[Operator Parser AExpr]]
aOperators =
    [ [Prefix (Neg <$ symbol "-") ]
    , [ InfixL (ABinary Multiply <$ symbol "*")
      , InfixL (ABinary Divide   <$ symbol "/") ]
    , [ InfixL (ABinary Add      <$ symbol "+")
      , InfixL (ABinary Subtract <$ symbol "-") ]
    ]
```

Using this I can correctly parse this:

```
1 + 2
```

Generating an AST like this.

```
(ABinary Add (IntConst 1) (IntConst 2))
```

Another thing I can parse are general expressions. These can be things such as variables, method calls, ternaries etc.

**E.g.**

**Identifiers:**

```
varName
```

This generates:

```
(Identifier (Name "varName"))
```

**Method Calls:**

```
methodCall()
```

This generates:

```
(MethodCall (Name "methodCall") (BlockExpr []))
```

Here's an example for parsing general expressions.

```
expressionParser :: Parser Expr
expressionParser
    =   methodCallParser
    <|> identifierParser
```

This works fine but I would also like to parse arithmetic expressions in this.

```
expressionParser :: Parser Expr
expressionParser
    =   newClassInstanceParser
    <|> methodCallParser
    <|> AExprAsExpr <$> aExpr
    <|> identifierParser
```

This means using the `expressionParser` I can now parse all the different expressions including arithmetic expressions. If it happens to be an arithmetic expression it gets wrapped in `AExprAsExpr`.

**Problem**

I would like to parse arithmetic expressions containing other expressions.

E.g.

```
x + y
```

To do this my original thought was to change the arithmetic parser so it also parses expressions.

```
data AExpr
    = ExprAsAExpr Expr
    | IntConst Integer
    | Neg AExpr
    | ABinary ABinOp AExpr AExpr
    deriving (Show, Eq)

aExpr :: Parser AExpr
aExpr = makeExprParser aTerm aOperators

aTerm :: Parser AExpr
aTerm
    =   parens aExpr
    <|> IntConst <$> integerParser
    <|> ExprAsAExpr <$> expressionParser

aOperators :: [[Operator Parser AExpr]]
aOperators =
    [ [Prefix (Neg <$ symbol "-") ]
    , [ InfixL (ABinary Multiply <$ symbol "*")
      , InfixL (ABinary Divide   <$ symbol "/") ]
    , [ InfixL (ABinary Add      <$ symbol "+")
      , InfixL (ABinary Subtract <$ symbol "-") ]
    ]
```

The problem with this is there is a recursive loop as `aTerm` calls the expression parser, the expression parser calls `aExpr`. This leads to an infinite loop. There is also the issue that all `identifiers` will now be wrapped inside an `AExprAsExpr`.

What is the correct method of parsing expressions inside arithmetic expressions?

Comment: If an arithmetic expression can be an expression and an expression can be an arithmetic expression, these shouldn't be separate things at all. Just merge the definitions of `aExpr` and `expressionParser`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** I just now realized that you are using `makeExpressionParser` and my answer doesn't really apply to that.  Anyway maybe this answer is still helpful?

Parsec is a type of recursive-descent parser, which means it cannot handle left recursion, as you are seeing.  You need to factor it out, which can always be done if the grammar is context-free.  One way you see this factorization done is by having a production for each precedence level.  Here is an example grammar for simple arithmetic:

```
expr ::= addExpr
addExpr ::= mulExpr '+' addExpr
          | mulExpr '-' addExpr
          | mulExpr
mulExpr ::= term '*' mulExpr
          | term '/' mulExpr
          | term
term ::= '(' expr ')'
       | number
```

Notice the pattern: the first symbol in each production calls down to the next more specific one.  Then explicit parentheses allow us to re-enter the top-level production.  This is generally how operator precedence is expressed in recursive descent.

The above grammar can only produce right-nested expressions.  While it will accept exactly the right strings, it does not correctly parse when the interpretation is left-associative.  In particular,

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4
```

will be parsed as

```
1 - (2 - (3 - 4))
```

which is not correct according to our conventions.  In a general recursive-descent parser you have to do some tricks to associate correctly here.  In Parsec, however, we have the `many` combinators, which we can use to our advantage.  For example, to parse left-associated subtraction, we could say

```
subExpr = foldl1 (-) <$> many1 mulExpr
```

The next level here are apparently the [`chainl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:chainl) combinators which seem to have been designed for just this purpose (though I just learned about it now -- guess I should have perused the docs more).  An example of using this would be

```
addExpr = chainl1 mulExpr oper
    where
    oper = choice [ (+) <$ symbol '+'
                  , (-) <$ symbol '-'
                  ]
```

I love writing parsers in Haskell.  Good luck!